# "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" when operating on array of strings

Tags: python, arrays

I will preface by saying that I am very new to python and Stack Overflow. I am attempting to do an operation on a bunch of different arrays. An example of one of these arrays would be

```
s2 = np.array( ['e','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','e','k',\
            'k','k','e','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','e','k','k','k','e','e',\
            'e','k','k','k','e','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','e','k','k','k','e','k'])
```

I am attempting to do a summation using nested for loops, but whenever I use the statement

```
for i in range(s2):
```

I get the error described above

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I am wondering how I would be able to tell python that I am looking specifically in this array, even though it is an array of strings, and it seems to want an integer array. Again, newbie here, so any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think you're using `range` correctly - just as a wild guess, does `for i in s2` do what you need?

Comment: Please read the documentation on `range`, and refer to your tutorial materials for how to iterate through a sequence.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial substitute.

Comment: ok thank you it was a problem with the range

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(s2):
```

range needs to have a number or len like range(len(s2)):

you can iterate this list like:

```
for item in s2:
   print(item)
```

or

```
for x in range(len(s2)):
   print(s2[x])
```

If you are trying to iterate over it in some other rather than one item at a time,  let me know

Comment: David, would you be so kind to bump me up a point if this helped :-)

Comment: Yes. I gave you a bump but since I am brand new here it didn't publicly show up unfortunately

Comment: oh i forgot about that. Well, if no one else answers  maybe you can checkmark me, lol. It's hard to get points on this site. I'm shooting for 1k. I'm still learning, i just gave you a star, my first one :-)